# get all date in current month and last month in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to get all dates in a current month and last month from today.like, if today is 24/02/2017 and i want to get dates like 24/02/2017,23/02/2017,22/02/2107-- to 23-01-2017 in SQL Server.

Comment: Hint: recursive CTE

Comment: please give me some detailed answer i am new to SQL

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `Recursive` cte

```
 with cte as
  (
  select getdate() as   n
  union all
  select  dateadd(DAY,-1,n) from cte where dateadd(dd,-1,n)> DATEADD(month, -1, getdate())
  )
  select * from cte
```

Comment: Thanks it works nice as i expected

Comment: Nice answer just do a minor adjust because in the example iterarion ends in 23/01 and your code ens in 25/01 two days early

Answer (score 1):

A simple **WHILE** will do the trick

```
declare
 @today date = getdate()
,@day date

set @day = @today

while @day >= DATEADD(month, -1, @today)
begin

select @day
set @day = DATEADD(day, -1, @day)

end
```

If you want it in a table just insert in a temp table this way. Also code corrected to iterate until **today** -1 **day** -1 **month** like in your example.

```
declare
 @today date = getdate()
,@day date

declare
@daysTable  table ([day] date not null)

set @day = @today

while @day >= DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(month, -1, @today))
begin

--select @day
insert into @daysTable values (@day)

set @day = DATEADD(day, -1, @day)

end

select * from @daysTable
```

Comment: Thanks, it helps me a lot